# RASA: Entry point not found - tensorflow\contrib\coder\python\ops\_coder_ops.so not found

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

Rasa Core version: 0.13.0a4
Python version: 3.6.1
Operating system: Windows 10

I could successfully train the model for the created stories using `python nlu_model.py`. But when I try to launch the bot in command prompt, I get an entry point not found error.

This link said that this might be a Tensorflow GPU issue, but I am not using GPU.
I tried to upgrade to the latest Tensorlow version, but still didnt work.

[image]

Comment: which TensorFlow version are you using?

Comment: Can you please try the solution from here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20320#issuecomment-440817373

Comment: @Tobias I am using TF 1.10.0. The comments in the link suggest to `follow the path and locate _dataset_ops.so`, but in my case, I don't have the file in that location already.